# MVC route to content to avoid other routes from matching?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, url-routing

In my MVC project I have a route like this:

```
routes.Add("MyRoute", new MyRoute("{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }));
```

I also have some bundles (showing only constructor with URL here):

```
new Bundle("~/Scripts/companyname", typeof(JsMinify));
new Bundle("~/Content/themes/companyname/css", typeof(Microsoft.Web.Optimization.CssMinify));
new Bundle("~/Content/skin/css", typeof(Microsoft.Web.Optimization.CssMinify));
new Bundle("~/Content/companyname_css", typeof(Microsoft.Web.Optimization.CssMinify));
new Bundle("~/Content/print_css", typeof(Microsoft.Web.Optimization.CssMinify));
```

I want those bundles to ***not*** be matched by `"MyRoute"`. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Found it. This is what `RouteCollection.IgnoreRoute` is for. I do find the documentation in this area pretty scarce, so I'll add a few details here.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("Scripts/{*pathInfo}");
```

Those lines tell the routing system to ignore URL:s that start with `Content/` and `Scripts/` respectively, and has "anything" after the `/`. The asterisk `*` in `{*pathInfo}` means that the `pathInfo` token should be assigned the remainder of the URL.

I have not been able to determine if the name `pathInfo` matters, or could be anything, but it appears that the pattern needs a placeholder there, with the leading asterisk, to match anything after the `/`.